# Need to iterate list of dictionaries in python and get only values of dict in a list form

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to get a list from the dictionaries which is in a list

I tried `[v for k,v in l[i].iteritems() for i in len(l) if k=='cell']`

Example:

```
 l = [{'cell':4,'num':55}, {'cell':5,'num':66}, {'cell':6,'num':77}]
```

I want to write a nested for loop in a single line and get output as

```
output = [4,5,6]
```

Comment: You just want the `'cell'` value?

Comment: A one liner answer if you only require the cell value is :

`[d['cell'] for d in l ]`

that would return the correct output for your example.

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez `[d['cell'] for d in l if 'cell' in d]` would be marginally better... OK the OP's dictionaries _always contain_ the `'cell'` key but it's better to avoid exceptions in a list comprehension, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you @CarlosGonzalez your answer gave me my requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'cell': 4, 'num': 55}, {'cell': 5, 'num': 66}, {'cell': 6, 'num': 77}]
ls = []
for i in l:
    ls.append(i['cell'])
print(ls)
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

it should work like this:

```
l = [{'cell':4,'num':55}, {'cell':5,'num':66}, {'cell':6,'num':77}]

list_new=[]
for i in l:
    list_new.append(i['cell'])
```